# Fetch specific Secret value for a specific key in AWS Secrets Manager via Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, key, aws-secrets-manager

I am fetching a secret from AWS Secrets Manager, but currently getting a list of all the key-value pairs. I just want secret value for a specific key in return.

```
Get-SECSecretValue -SecretId "secret-arn" -Select SecretString
```

I was not able to find any solution on internet sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ConvertFrom-Json to parse the json response and then use json object to get the corresponding value.

```
username = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject (Get-SECSecretValue -SecretId secret-arn ).SecretString).username
```

Comment: `Get-SECSecretValue` works in theory but not in practice.  There are other dependencies with `AWS.Tools.SecretsManager` that are surprisingly finnicky to provision. It would be awesome to have a pure Powershell 7.x-based approach.